# Read or Write File Using Thread

Tags: java, synchronization, thread-safety

I want  program for  read and write file.I want to perform any one of operation(read or write) at a time.If i'm reading file, write request waits untill read operation finish.If I writing file then read request waits untill write operation finish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a class to do the reading and writing, and make it fully synchronized, for example:

```
public class MyFileManager{
  private static MyFileManager instance;

  public static synchronized MyFileManager getInstance(){ // to use as singelton
    if(instance==null){
      instance=new MyFileManager();
    }
    return instance;
  }

  private MyFileManager(){} // to avoid creation of new instances


 public synchronized String read(File f){
   //Do Something
 }

 public synchronized void write(File f, String s){
   //Do Something
 }

}
```

now when you want to read or write, just do

```
String s=MyFileManager.getInstance.read(myfile);
MyFileManager.getInstance.write(myfile,"hello world!");
```

Comment: you know you can vote up if u like this answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a mutex. It's a structure that allow only one thread to use a ressource at a time. Look around ReentrantLock.